# Python argument passing in object oriented programming

Tags: python, oop, arguments

I apologize if this was asked somewhere else, but I do not know how else to formulate this question.

I am a physicist and Python is my first object-oriented language. I love this language for its clean code, and somehow everything works as intended (by me ;).

However I have one problem, maybe it is more of a design choice, but since my object oriented programming is self-taught and very basic I am not sure which way to go.

So the question is: should I mainly pass arguments or manipulate the object data directly? Because, for instance:

```
class test(object):

    ...

    def dosomething(self, x, y):
        # do someting with x, y involving a lot of mathematic manipulations

    def calcit(self):
        k = self.dosomething(self.x[i], self.y[i])
        # do something else with k
```

produces much cleaner code than not passing `x, y` but passing `i` and writing the `self` explicitly every time. What do you prefer, or is this an object oriented paradigm that I am breaking?

Performance-wise this shouldn't make a difference since the arguments are passed by reference, right?

Comment: Try to use some way to distinguish words inside function names, for example `calc_it` or `do_something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object paradigm is that :
you pack up methods and attributes together and call them an object.

So, if you manipulate precisely one of those attributes you don't need to pass them as parameters, you SHOULD use the object's ones. If you use anything else then you got to pass it as parameters.

And nothing prevents you from getting the values of your object into another variable if it bothers you to write self every time !

To finish, your function that takes x and y as parameters should not be in your object but outside of it as an helper function if you really wanna do something like that, the reason being that there is no reason to pass your object as first parameter (even if it's implicit) if you do not use it.

and yeah performance wise it should be pretty similar !

Comment: even though it does not change the outside appearance of the object? disregarding that for instance exp(- 1j * x * y) is much more readable than exp(- 1j * self.x[i] * self.y[i])?

Comment: What do you mean about appearance ?
If you mean that it doesn't change the value of any of your object's attributes then you have two cases :
- it returns a value that depends on one of those object's values, then it's ok
- it takes external parameters only and computes them, then it should be outside of your object.

About the readability, you can start your function with x, y = self.x[i], self.y[i] and now you have your values AND it's readable !

Comment: first case applies, i guess i am a minimalist and x, y = self.x[i]... seemed like a unnecessary line of code

Comment: if it makes the rest of your function way more readable don't hesitate :)

Comment: Notice that you already have `x, y = self.x[i], self.y[i]`. Left part (`x, y`) is in method arguments definition, right part is at call site.

Comment: @yak : you didn't read properly the previous comments I think.

Answer (score 4):

> should i mainly pass arguments or manipulate the object data directly

Think of objects as systems with a state. If data belongs to the state of the object, then it should be packaged in the object as a member. Otherwise, it should be passed to its methods as an argument.

In your example, what you should do depends on whether you want to `dosomething` on values `x` and `y` that are not members of the object. If you don't, then you can have `dosomething` fetch `x` and `y` from `self`.

Also, keep in mind that if you're not using `self` inside a method, then it probably shouldn't be a method at all but rather a freestanding function.

> performance-wise this shouldn't make a difference since the arguments are passed by reference, right?

I wouldn't worry about performance at this point at all.

Comment: +1 and I've seen a lot of bad code that was written because it *performs so much better* in program parts where performance was rather unimportant.

Comment: agreed, especially when you're a beginner, aim to write clean code, not fast one. You'll end up having way faster code in the end this way, anyway.

Comment: im not a beginner in general but a beginner in oop, and i think it can make a difference if you unnecessary duplicate a large data array